# Kendo details grid returns invalid template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I got 2 grids, one is in the details template of the other as the code below, but when I try to run this code it returns error saying Invalid Template, since the 2 grids are absolutely identical I can't understand why the details template brakes. If I remove some columns as a whole and from 2 columns the custom editor templates it works,  but I need it to work as it is defined right now. Any ideas what might cause this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("res")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Title("ID").Width(50);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Type).EditorTemplateName("DropdownType").ClientTemplate("#=Type.Value#").Title("Type").Width(160);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Org).EditorTemplateName("DropdownOrg").ClientTemplate("#=Org.Value#").Title("Org").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name").Width(150);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity).EditorTemplateName("Double").Title("Quantity").Width(80);
                columns.Bound(p => p.QuantityUOM).EditorTemplateName("DropdownQuantityUOM").ClientTemplate("#=QuantityUOM.Value#").Title("Quantity UOM").Width(80);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Area).ClientTemplate("#= Area.Value #").EditorTemplateName("DropdownAreas").Title("Area of Operation").Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Date).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("Date").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ETA).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("ETA").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Arrived).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Arrived").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= Arrived ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>").Width(60);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Status).ClientTemplate("#=Status.Value#").EditorTemplateName("DropdownStatus").Title("Status").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Tactical).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Tactical").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsTactical ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>").Width(60);

            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Save();
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Navigatable()
            .Filterable()
            .Events(e =>
            {
                e.FilterMenuInit("initCheckboxFilter");
            })
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height(320))
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Groupable()
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
            })
            .Read(read =>
                        read.Action("Read", "Controller")
                            .Data("filterByPeriod")
                 )
            .Create("Create", "Controller")
            .Update("Update", "Controller")
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Controller"))
            )
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("resourceTemplate")
    )
    <script type="text/kendo" id="resourceTemplate">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("resObj")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Title("ID").Width(50);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Type).EditorTemplateName("DropdownType").ClientTemplate("#=Type.Value#").Title("Type").Width(160);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Org).EditorTemplateName("DropdownOrg").ClientTemplate("#=Org.Value#").Title("Org").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name").Width(150);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity).EditorTemplateName("Double").Title("Quantity").Width(80);
                columns.Bound(p => p.QuantityUOM).EditorTemplateName("DropdownQuantityUOM").ClientTemplate("#=QuantityUOM.Value#").Title("Quantity UOM").Width(80);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Area).ClientTemplate("#= Area.Value #").EditorTemplateName("DropdownAreas").Title("Area of Operation").Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Date).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("Date").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ETA).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("ETA").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Arrived).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Arrived").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= Arrived ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>").Width(60);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Status).ClientTemplate("#=Status.Value#").EditorTemplateName("DropdownStatus").Title("Status").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Tactical).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Tactical").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsTactical ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>").Width(60);
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Navigatable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
            })

            .Read(read =>
                        read.Action("Read", "Controller",
                                 new { ID = "#=ID#" }))

            .Create("Create", "Controller")
            .Update("Update", "Controller")
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Controller"))
            )
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("clientTemplate")
        )
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("res")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Title("ID").Width(50);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Save();
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Navigatable()
            .Filterable()
            .Events(e =>
            {
                e.FilterMenuInit("initCheckboxFilter");
            })
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height(320))
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Groupable()
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
            })
            .Read(read =>
                        read.Action("Read", "Controller")
                            .Data("filterByPeriod")
                 )
            .Create("Create", "Controller")
            .Update("Update", "Controller")
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Controller"))
            )
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("resourceTemplate")
    )
    <script type="text/kendo" id="resourceTemplate">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("resObj")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Title("ID");
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Navigatable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
            })

            .Read(read =>
                        read.Action("Read", "Controller",
                                 new { ID = "#=ID#" }))

            .Create("Create", "Controller")
            .Update("Update", "Controller")
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Controller"))
            )
            .ToClientTemplate()
        )
</script>
```

Comment: add the template that's causing the problem; also - removing which editor templates + columns makes it work?

Comment: Removing the checkbox columns, removing the dropdown templates